# How to use words directly in nltk grammar

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to extract a company name form a given German address using python NLTK.
This is the code I used,

```
import nltk

address="CompanyName GmbH * Keltenstr. 16 * 123456 Kippenheim * Deutschland"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(address)
textTokens = nltk.Text(tokens)
POStagList = nltk.pos_tag(textTokens)
print(POStagList)

grammar = """
        NP: 
            {<NN.?|JJ|FW>GmbH}"""


cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(POStagList)

for subtree in result.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'NP'):
   print("NP Subtree:", subtree)
```

I need the output: **CompanyName GmbH**

Sometimes instead of **GmbH** it may be **corp** or **Inc.** or **llc** , etc

How to solve this?

How to use string values & escape sequence characters directly inside grammar?

Comment: Does it work? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Can you not simply split the string on the `*` characters and use the first item?

Comment: its not working. I need the correct grammar for to obtain the result "CompanyName GmbH"

Comment: Can you explain *how* it does not work? What do you get instead of `CompanyName GmbH`? Is there an error message?

Comment: I need to get the result using grammars. I have to some more grammars for another format of addresses

Comment: [('CompanyName', 'NNP'), ('GmbH', 'NNP'), ('*', 'NNP'), ('Keltenstr', 'NNP'), ('.', '.'), ('16', 'CD'), ('*', 'JJ'), ('123456', 'CD'), ('Kippenheim', 'NNP'), ('*', 'CD'), ('Deutschland', 'NNP')]                                                                                                                                          This is the output I got.                                                                                 Output of the statement print(POStagList)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mixing grammar with literal strings, you may use a work around using regex: tag the tokens with POS, and then only grab those tokens you need before known words (like `GmbH`).

The code will look like

```
import nltk
import re
address="CompanyName GmbH * Keltenstr. 16 * 123456 Kippenheim * Deutschland"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(address)
textTokens = nltk.Text(tokens)
POStagList = nltk.pos_tag(textTokens)
joined = ' '.join(["{}<{}>".format(word,tag) for word,tag in POStagList])
grammar = r'NN[^>]?|JJ|FW' # regex! 
print([re.sub("<(?:{})>".format(grammar), "", x.strip()) for x in re.findall(r'((?:\S+<(?:{0})> )+)(?:GmbH|Inc|corp|llc)<(?:{0})>'.format(grammar), joined)])
```

Output: `['CompanyName']`.

Here, the grammar is specified using a regex like `NN[^>]?|JJ|FW` where `[^>]?` matches any char but `>` (just to make sure we do not match `>`, as `.` would do). After that, [`((?:\S+<(?:NN[^>]?|JJ|FW)> )+)(?:GmbH|Inc|corp|llc)<(?:NN[^>]?|JJ|FW)>`](https://regex101.com/r/BnoJG6/1) regex will find all the matches you need, but since they contain tags, they must be removed with a `re.sub` with a mere `<(?:NN[^>]?|JJ|FW)>` regex.

The main regex details:

- `((?:\S+<(?:NN[^>]?|JJ|FW)> )+)` - Group 1: one or more sequences of 1+ non-whitespace chars followed with `<`, then `NN` + any 1 or 0 chars other than `>`,  or `JJ` or `FW`, and then `>` and then a space
- `(?:GmbH|Inc|corp|llc)` - any of the alternatives: `GmbH`, `Inc`, `corp` or `llc`
- `<(?:NN[^>]?|JJ|FW)>` - `<`, `NN` + any 1 or 0 chars other than `>`,  or `JJ` or `FW`.

Comment: But is there a way to mix grammar with literal strings? Is there a way to solve this just by using RegexpParser with regex like  {<NN.?|JJ|FW>GmbH|PLC|LTD|Inc}, or something like that?

Comment: @taga I have never found a way to do that directly.